# Messages on flutter chat app not in proper order

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've just completed a basic chat app based on a tutorial. New messages should be shown at bottom but that isn't happening.

When I remove, save and again add `reversed` in line :
`final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;`

Then it seems to reorder properly, but the very next message is random again.

The only difference is I'm using a more updated firebase plugins.

`firebase_core: 0.4.0+8` tutorial was `^0.3.4`
`firebase_auth: 0.14.0+1` tutorial was `^0.8.4+4`
`cloud_firestore: 0.12.9`  tutorial was `^0.9.13+1`

MessageStream Code :

```
class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (!snapshot.hasData) {
return Center(
child: CircularProgressIndicator(
 backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
    ),
  );
}
final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
for (var message in messages) {
  final messageText = message.data['text'];
  final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

  final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

  final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
    sender: messageSender,
    text: messageText,
    isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
  );

  messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
}
return Expanded(
  child: ListView(
    reverse: true,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 10.0),
    children: messageBubbles,
    ),
   );
  },
);
}
}
```

Apart from the random order, everything works fine and messages are saved in firebase. Maybe I need to add timecode or something else to make it work.

Any help is appreciated - Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

After applying this code delete the database in the firebase just as Angela did in her course video.And then restart the app. Your app will work. Also, in the code I have add instruction about those things which you have to add. Add them only. 
I faced the same problem so i took the help of a coder to resolve this. So it will work in your code too.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final _fireStore = Firestore.instance;
FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static String chatScreen = 'ChatScreenpage1';
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  String messageText;

  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserDetail();
  }

  void getUserDetail() async {
    try {
      final createdUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (createdUser != null) {
        loggedInUser = createdUser;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {

                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreambuilderClass(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextEditingController,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextEditingController.clear();
                      _fireStore.collection('messages').add({
                        'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                        'text': messageText,
                        'time': FieldValue.serverTimestamp() //add this
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StreambuilderClass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _fireStore
            .collection('messages')
            .orderBy('time', descending: false)//add this
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              ),
            );
          }
          final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
          List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
          for (var message in messages) {
            final messageText = message.data['text'];
            final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
            final messageTime = message.data['time'] as Timestamp; //add this
            final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

            final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
              sender: messageSender,
              text: messageText,
              isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
              time: messageTime, //add this
            );

            messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
          }

          return Expanded(
            child: ListView(
                reverse: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                children: messageBubbles),
          );
        });
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final String sender;
  final bool isMe;
  final Timestamp time; // add this

  MessageBubble({this.text, this.sender, this.isMe, this.time}); //add the variable  in this constructor
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            ' $sender ${DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time.seconds * 1000)}',// add this only if you want to show the time along with the email. If you dont want this then don't add this DateTime thing
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 12),
          ),
          Material(
            color: isMe ? Colors.blueAccent : Colors.white,
            borderRadius: isMe
                ? BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))
                : BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(30)),
            elevation: 6,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 15),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20, color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe you can better explain the problem with the question's code instead of pasting the whole code a second time. Also, nobody cares about Angela, whoever that is :-) (I *assume* the gist is, firestore does not guarantee to keep the creation order, and you have to add a property (time) you can use for sorting?)

Comment: I understand your concern. But i found that complete code would be a better means of understanding this whole problem. As this code was a part of Angela's course, so i believe that it would be easier for those who had taken her course to understand. I just added timestamp here and ordered all the message by time by creating a time field in the database along with sender and text fields.

Comment: Hi, does this code also update the chat screen when new message is sent by any user at the same time? I am look for a code where I just don't call firestore query to get messages when i open the chat screen, i want if any user is online and texting it should show the msgs they sent there only. is it possibles?

Comment: We are using stream builder which automatically fetches messages from firestore, whenever a user send a message. It does the job what we expect from a basic chat app where users enter a message and it is shown to other users at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the full working solution. Thanks to jquevedo and appbrewery.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
FirebaseUser loggedInUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "chat_screen";

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final messageTextContoller = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  String messageText;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void messagesStream() async {
    await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection("messages").snapshots()) {
      for (var message in snapshot.documents) {
        print(message.data);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            MessagesStream(),
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: messageTextContoller,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextContoller.clear();
                      _firestore.collection("messages").add({
                        "text": messageText,
                        "sender": loggedInUser.email,
                        "time": DateTime.now()
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection("messages").snapshots(),
      // ignore: missing_return
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.documents;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data["sender"];
          final messageTime = message.data["time"];
          final currentUsser = loggedInUser.email;
          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            time: messageTime,
            isMe:  currentUsser == messageSender,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
          messageBubbles.sort((a , b ) => b.time.compareTo(a.time));
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class MessageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final Timestamp time;
  final bool isMe;

  MessageBubble({this.sender, this.text, this.isMe, this.time});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "$sender ${time.toDate()}",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey,
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
          ),
          Material(
            borderRadius: isMe ? BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ) : BorderRadius.only(
              topRight: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
            ),
            elevation: 5.0,
            color: isMe ? Colors.lightBlueAccent : Colors.purpleAccent,
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 10,
                horizontal: 20,
              ),
              child: Text(
                text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the additional two statements in your code to get the ordered result. I have put dots for the same code.

```
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _firestore.collection('messages').orderBy('date').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
      );
    }
    ....
FlatButton(
                   onPressed: () {
                   messageTextController.clear();
                  _firestore.collection("messages").add({
                    'sender': loggedInUser.email,
                    'text': messageText,
                    'date': DateTime.now().toIso8601String().toString(),
                  });
                  },
           ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var notSortedMEssages = snapshot.data.documents;
notSortedMEssages.sort((a,b) => a['time'].compareTo(b['time']);
var reversedSortedMEssages = List.from(notSortedMEssages.reversed);
List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included an explanation of how this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Timestamp'

Comment: I could not understand how it is related to the author question. Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

 final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Message")
        .orderBy("time", descending: true)
        .snapshots();

  firestore.collection('Message').add({
                        "Email": _auth.currentUser!.email,
                        "message": message,
                        "time": DateTime.now(),
                      });
```