# Cloud Firebase list reversal

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am creating a simple chat app using Cloud Firebase, but sometime when i am adding text it is getting added in random position, although I have used `reversed` to reverse the list, can anyone have some idea to solve it...
hers's my code...

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
User loggedinUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String route = '/chat';
  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final messageTextController =
      TextEditingController(); // to remove the sent message from the textbox

  String messageText;
  void getCurrentUser() async {
    /*
    * Default is null; as user logs in it contains some value
    * */
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        loggedinUser = user;
        loggedinUser.email;
        //print('res************************************: $recentLoggedInUser');
      }
    } catch (e) {}
  }

//  void getMessages() async {
//    final messages = await _firestore.collection('messages').get();
//    for (var message in messages.docs) {
//      print(message.data());
//    }
//  }

//  void messagesStream() async {
//    await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
//      for (var message in snapshot.docs) {
//        print(message.data());
//      }
//    }
//  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                // messagesStream();
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            messageStreams(), // Just get the stream here to populate
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      controller:
                          messageTextController, // this controller handels the text after being sent
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      /*
                      * add method receives a map that accepts <String, dynamic> format;
                      * field name should be same as defined into firebase portal
                      * */
                      // use the controller to clear the text box as soon as it is sent
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'sender': loggedinUser.email,
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class messageStreams extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.docs.reversed;
//            .reversed; // reversed make a list in reversed order, so newest will appear at lowest
        List<messageBubble> messagewidgets = [];
        for (var m in messages) {
          final messageText = m.get('text');
          final senderText = m.get('sender'); // get sender email from DB

          var recentLogger = loggedinUser.email;
          CrossAxisAlignment c = recentLogger == senderText
              ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
              : CrossAxisAlignment.start;

          final messageWidgit = messageBubble(
            sender: senderText,
            text: messageText,
            crossAxisAlignments: c,
          );
          messagewidgets.add(messageWidgit);
        }
        /*
                * As we have Container, we will use expanded, this way it will take only the part that is necessary
                * */
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10.0,
              vertical: 20.0,
            ),
            children: messagewidgets,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class messageBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final sender;
  final text;
  CrossAxisAlignment crossAxisAlignments;

  messageBubble({this.sender, this.text, this.crossAxisAlignments});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BorderRadius br;
    Color clr;
    if (crossAxisAlignments == CrossAxisAlignment.start) {
      br = BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
      );
      clr = Colors.lightBlueAccent;
    } else if (crossAxisAlignments == CrossAxisAlignment.end) {
      br = BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
      );
      clr = Colors.blueAccent;
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: crossAxisAlignments,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12.0,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
          BuildChatList(br, clr),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Material BuildChatList(BorderRadius br, Color clr) {
    return Material(
      borderRadius: br,
      elevation: 5.0,
      color: clr,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
        child: Text(
          '$text',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 15.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//BorderRadius.only(
//topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
//bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
//bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
//)
```

Please follow the image:
[image]

here i have got what's up on the top, rather I did it after 2 messages.

Can anyone help me to solve the issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add orderBy() to descend sorting the message. for example firestore.collection('messages').orderBy("created_at", descending: true).snapshots(),

Comment: i hope you will find the solution her
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61517928/18529170

Answer (score 1):

You can add orderBy() to descend sorting the message. for example firestore.collection('messages').orderBy("created_at", descending: true).snapshots().